# Centering a dynamically-sized `titleView` in navigation bar without autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, titleview

I'm new to iOS layouts, and I'm trying to programmatically centre a custom view (actually a React Native `RCTRootView` which extends `UIView`, if that's relevant) which has intrinsically sized, dynamic content (defined over in javascript land).

I've seen solutions overriding `intrinsicallySizedContent` but that seems to be only relevant to auto-layout, which isn't used by RN. The only way I've been able measure the size of the `RCTRootView`'s content is by adding it to a view, and waiting over several passes of `layoutSubViews` until its `frame` has a size. That led me to the following effort:

### Attempt: Wrap and set wrapper size in layoutSubViews

I'm wrapping the `RCTRootView` in another `UIView` and trying to override `layoutSubViews`, setting the size of my wrapping frame once I have the size of the react native content.

My wrapper is created and added to the navigation bar in my `UIViewController` like this:

```
  RCTBridge *bridge = ((RCTRootView*)self.view).bridge;
  RCTRootView *reactView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:navBarCustomView initialProperties:initialProps];
  RCCCustomTitleView *titleView = [[TitleWrapperView alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds subView:reactView];
  self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
  self.navigationItem.titleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

And the wrapper is implemented like this:

```
#import "TitleWrapperView.h"
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@interface TitleWrapperView ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) RCTRootView *subView;
@end

@implementation TitleWrapperView // Extends UIView

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame subView:(RCTRootView*)subView {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    
    if (self) {
        self.subView = subView;
        self.subView.sizeFlexibility = RCTRootViewSizeFlexibilityWidthAndHeight;
        self.clipsToBounds = true;

        // Prevent the wrapper from being so large initially as to squash the '< Back' button down to '<'
        self.frame = CGRectZero;

        [self addSubview:subView];
    }
    
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect contentViewFrame = self.subView.contentView.frame;
    if (contentViewFrame.size.width > 0) {
        // Once we have a measurement for the sub-view's content, set the wrapper's frame
        if (self.frame.size.width != contentViewFrame.size.width) {
            self.frame = contentViewFrame;
        }
    }
}
@end
```

That works a treat on iOS 11+, but not on iOS 10.3, where when the screen containing the custom nav (the red box) is pushed, the navigation transition animates the `titleView` over towards the top left, rather than into the centre (the end position, which is correct) as I'd hope:

[image]

### Other approaches?

There might be a way to overcome the iOS 10 glitch above (and I'd love to hear it) but I'm fairly certain there must be a better approach. Is is possible to allow an arbitrary, complex view to lay itself out and get its measurement before adding it to a parent? I've also tried overriding `sizeThatFits` in my wrapper, which is called by the navigation bar, and requesting the size of my `RCTRootView` using `[subView sizeThatFits: myLargeContainer]`, but I get `0,0` back.

I'm at a loss - any pointers are appreciated.